# Proof Parseval's relation with polarization

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have to show Parseval's relation for $f,g \in L^2(T^n)$ where $T^n$ ist the n-dimensional Torus. The inner product is given by: 
$$ \langle f \vert g\rangle = \int_{T^n} f(t) \overline{g(t)}dt$$
Parseval's relation: $$\int_{T^n} f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z^n}} \hat f(m) \overline{\hat g (m)} $$
I can use the following equality $$ \Vert f \Vert_{L^2}^2 = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z^n}} \vert \hat f (m) \vert^2$$

The given hint was to use the polarization: 
$$ 4\langle f \vert g \rangle= \Vert f+g\Vert_{L^2}^2 - \Vert f-g\Vert_{L^2}^2 + i\Vert f+ig\Vert_{L^2}^2 - i \Vert f-ig\Vert_{L^2}^2$$My question is how I can combine the polarization and the given equality to show the result.

Comment: This works for complex numbers, $z,w$ too:  $4z\overline{w} = \sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n|z+i^nw|^2$.